# Deno: How to run shell command and read output before child process completes?

Tags: shell, google-chrome-devtools, deno

How do I launch a child process (via shell) and read its output without (before) the child process returns?

I"m launching Google Chrome via the Mac Terminal with the following command:
`/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222 --no-first-run --no-default-browser-check --user-data-dir=$(mktemp -d -t 'chrome-remote_data_dir')` 
This works well but the process does not end/return until I'me done with the browser.  As soon as its launched, however, it prints the following to the console:
"DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9222/devtools/browser/d43342be-66bc-41d4-b591-a7ee22d1c528"

I need to scrape that.  I can successfully launch this in Deno (v. 1.36.3) using:

```
const myCMD = `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome`;

const p = Deno.run({
  cmd: [
    myCMD,
    "--remote-debugging-port=9222",
    "--no-first-run",
    "--no-default-browser-check",
    "--user-data-dir=$(mktemp -d -t 'chrome-remote_data_dir')",
  ],
  stdout: "piped",
  stderr: "piped",
  stdin: "piped",
});

await p.stdin.write(new TextEncoder().encode("Coming from stdin\n"));
await p.status();
```

But I can't read the value I need because the process does not complete and therefore the output never returns.  Is there a way to read what a child process writes to the console before it returns?

FYI... I used the following article for reference: https://medium.com/deno-the-complete-reference/run-shell-commands-in-deno-26c3e9b72e03

Comment: FWIW, you can get the socket directly without scraping by making a request to localhost:9222/json/version, see https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/#endpoints

Comment: Thank you wOxxOm.  That ultimately solved my issue in a much more elegant manner.  I'm embarrassed I didn't think of that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read from `p.stdout` and `p.stderr`, both are an instance of [`FsFile`](https://deno.land/api@v1.36.4?s=Deno.FsFile) so you can use `.readable` to access the [`ReadableStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream) or use the `.read` method of `FsFile`

```js
const myCMD = `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome`;

const p = Deno.run({
  cmd: [
    myCMD,
    "--remote-debugging-port=9222",
    "--no-first-run",
    "--no-default-browser-check",
    "--user-data-dir=$(mktemp -d -t 'chrome-remote_data_dir')",
  ],
  stdout: "piped",
  stderr: "piped",
  stdin: "piped",
});

(async() => {
   for await(const chunk of p.stdout.readable) {
       console.log(chunk, new TextDecoder().decode(chunk))
   }
})();

(async() => {
    for await(const chunk of p.stderr.readable) {
        console.log(chunk, new TextDecoder().decode(chunk))
    }
})();

await p.stdin.write(new TextEncoder().encode("Coming from stdin\n"));
await p.status();
```

Now you'll see the output of the process.